# Trying to access response data using url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying something simple where I make a request from the front-end and fetch the JSON data on the back-end. I'm using ReactJS on the front-end and NodeJS and ExpressJS on the Back-end.

I am getting little confused with figure what the right way how I can access JSON data onto the front-end by make the name server file name from server.js or con.now.

I am getting in my console not it refused to connect the link to the server. I have been tried to name the file `server.js` to `cors.now` would that connect the server to the front-end but I was wrong.

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

But when every do that getting an error message in my console that talks about `cors.now.sh/https://us-central1-aaronklaser-1.cloudfunctions.net/medium?username=@aaron.klaser`

**Medium.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PageHeader from './PageHeader';
import PageContent from './PageContent';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Medium extends React.Component {

  state = {
    posts: []
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPosts().then(this.setPosts)

  }

  fetchPosts = () => axios.get(`https://cors.now.sh/https://us-central1-aaronklaser-1.cloudfunctions.net/medium?username=@aaron.klaser`)

  setPosts = response => {
    this.setState({
      posts: response

    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PageHeader/>
        <PageContent>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.posts, null, 2)}</pre>
        </PageContent>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**cors.now**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; 
const request = require('request'); 


app.get("/api/medium", (req, res) => {
    if(!req.query.username){
        return res.status(400).send('Error: You need to include query param ?username=@yourUsername');
    } else {
      return request(url,(error, response, body) => {
          const url = `https://medium.com/${req.query.username}/latest?format=json`;
          const prefix = `])}while(1);</x>`
          const strip = payload => payload.replace(prefix, ``)
          res.send(JSON.parse(strip(body)));
      });
    } 
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Do you have any adblocker available? Had a lot of issues related to that on my last project, also, try that on a different browser and see if the problem persists

Comment: No, don't have any adblocker available.

Comment: No, don't have any adblocker available. I have tried Chrome and Firefox still get the same error message saying that  CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using the https://cors.now.sh site as a reverse proxy. I am not sure if that site is functioning at this time?

If you hit your API endpoint directly (https://us-central1-aaronklaser-1.cloudfunctions.net/medium?username=@aaron.klaser) - I see a valid JSON response returned to the browser.

I believe the issue is with the reverse proxy site not running or responding at this time.